# How to allow popup new window from "WebBrowser control" in winform

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-11

I have used webbrowser control in winform and opening one of tableau URL dynamically.

Now, when tableau url page contain any inner link which popup the new window then, it should allow to open new window. But, presently, it gives me javascript error dialog as "An error has occured in the script on this page".

It works fine when i open that URL on browser then it open new URL when i click at link.
+
Plase suggest me how i could allow this to be work.

I dont' have control on tableau url as it was created by some one else and it contains some explorer data utility which popup new internet explorer window, it works fine in browser as well as some of machine as mentioned in "update" tag below.

Update:

It works fine in other machines, but not working in one particular machine.
Looks like, there are some issues with INTERNET EXPLORER SETTING.
USING IE 11.

I observed - web security policy link is disabled where its not working, how to enable it ?

Thanks

Comment: Use  mentioned link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470192/allow-popups-in-wpf-webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

You can not open a "new browser window" out of a Web-Browser control AFAIK, but you can catch "navigation events". If there is any way (I guess the "tableau page" is not created by you) to change that "javascipt pop-up code" to a normal link you could catch that and open the target page in a new Form or in the default browser by executing something like:

```
Process.Start(url); // if you "execute" a URL it will open in the default browser
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the content of the script error?

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/20/making-the-web-browser-control-launch-the-default-browser.aspx for discussion about invoking the system's default browser from a Web Browser Control.